# Find a 3D function knowing the numerical gradient in discrete point (mesh)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, discrete-mathematics, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

I have a rectangular mesh of dimension $n,m$ and a scalar field $\theta(x,y)$ defined over the different nodes of the mesh. I want to link $\theta(x,y)$ to an initial condition [level-set function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level-set_method) $ \phi $ using this relation:

$$ \theta(x,y) = \frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan \Bigg( \frac{\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}} \Bigg) $$

Since there are infinite functions that verify the above relation I've added another dummy constraint:

$$ \| \nabla \phi \| = 1 \implies \sqrt{(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})^2 + (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y})^2} = 1$$
$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = \pm \sqrt{1-(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y})^2}$$

I know the scalar field $\theta(x,y)$ everywhere, and with the two relation written above, I also know the numerical value of the gradient of the function.

So right now, I would integrate the first relation to find $\phi$, but I'm completely blocked. I don't know exactly how to deal with such a discrete problem. I need the value of the function $\phi$ over the nodes of the mesh. I was thinking to integrate

$$ \int d\phi = \int \sqrt{\frac{\tan^2(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta(x,y))}{\tan^2(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta(x,y))+1}} \:\:dy$$

and I've tried to implement it in MATLAB without results.

Have you any idea on how to deal with such a problem?

PS: I can if needed query my MATLAB script to get more points for $\theta(x,y)$.

Thanks in advance!
Enrico

Answer (score 1):

I've done few steps for your problem: the first equation is equivalent to
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\cot(\theta(x,y))=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}$$
I replaced this to second equation:
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}^2+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}^2\cot^2(\theta(x,y)) = 1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cot^2(\theta(x,y))+1}}$$
Similarly for $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}$, we obtain
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{\cot^2(\theta(x,y))}{\cot^2(\theta(x,y))+1}}$$

It is not guaranteed the existence of the function $\phi$. You can find more in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think that it's better to solve it as a linear integral or should I treat it as a PDE??

Comment: Yes, That is a good idea for treating it as a PDE. You can try to solve the first equation by using "Method of characteristics": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

Comment: And do you know how to deal with the $\pm$??

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't add the constraint $||\nabla \phi|| = 1$, The equation (1) is enough to solve the problem (maybe we will need an initial condition).

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Also because I implemented the firs approach of what this [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340719/numerically-find-a-potential-field-from-gradient) suggests and the solution is heavily influenced by the order of integration. So you advise me to treat it as a PDE? It introduces the big problem of boundary condition, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, we will have to duel with boundary conditions depending on your problem. But if we do your way and assume the existence of $\phi$, we will have a huge problem with the integral. I already tried to do your way.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use any Dirichlet or Neumann conditions: I'm only concerned about the iso-value line of the function $\phi$. And yes, you were correct, because when I switch the integration order (first x and then y and vice versa) and numerically calculate the gradient of $\phi$, only one of the two components of the gradient is correct.

Comment: Could you give me the formula of $\theta$? I will try to solve the equation by using the characteristic method.

Comment: Unfortunately, theta comes from an optimization problem, so it's only numerically defined. I've interpolated it with `fit` function. You can find the results [here](https://transfernow.net/ddl/theta). You can access to theta simply invoking  `theta = surface_smooth(x,y)`

Comment: Thank you for your function. I had expected the value of the $\theta$ will between $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ because of the function $\tan$ (or $\cot$). However, after drawing with Matlab, I saw $\theta$'s values can be any number. As you might know that $\tan(\pi/2)=\infty$. The point here is that there are some values of $\theta$ such that the $\tan(\theta)$ or $\cot(\theta)$ may not define.

Comment: I will try to solve this as PDEs without boundary conditions. Maybe we will have more information.

Comment: Since I'm using $\cot(\theta)$, $\theta$ vary between 0 and $\pi$.

Comment: My domain is 80 (x) X 40 (y)